# Sumar array despues que lea el primero

Tags: javascript

Sumar array despues que lea el primero.  ejemplo  el for recorre el array y lo divide por la escala, luego debe de recorrer el 2 pero debe sumarle el primero, luego recorre el 3 y le suma el 1 y el segundo. luego recorre el 3 y le suma el 1 y el segundo. y asi hasta que termine.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las imágenes, no sólo hacen imposible copiar tu código para probarlo, sino que también pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en celulares que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). ¿Podrías por favor incluir el código y el mensaje de error como texto? Encontrarás el enlace para **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta. Luego de pegarlo, hay que seleccionar el código completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```js
var arrText = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var escala = 2;
var distancia, aux = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < arrText.length; i++){
 distancia = (arrText[i] + aux) / escala;
 aux = aux + arrText[i];

 console.log('Suma de array, posicion: '+i+', total:', aux);
}
```

Saludos,

Comment: Perdon ignore la aux, estaba haciendo una prueba pero no me funciono

Comment: Disculpa, no entiendo bien el mensaje, ignoraste el aux, o yo debo ignorar el aux? Que es lo que no funciona, que aux agrege en cada vuelta el siguiente valor de arrText[i]; ?

Comment: Ignore el aux no sirve para nada.